# JQuery slide/toggle effect crashes

Tags: html, rows, slidetoggle, cells, effect

I have done the following HTML 1row-table which has a sliding/toggle effect made with jQuery. The hidden content can be showed up by clicking on the purple cell (Cell #1), on the left.

http://jsfiddle.net/jrick/6r5de/2/

Problems I need to resolve:

- The yellow cell disappears mysteriously when clicking on it, How can I avoid this?
- Then I want to add more rows below, with the same effect of the first one. I have tried myself but when sliding down the hidden yellow cells, the purple ones overlay one over the other, and the row alignment gets disrupted. This is what it happens:

http://jsfiddle.net/jrick/uv68r/5/

But it should look more or less like this in expanded state:

```
    -----------------------------------------
   | Cell #1| hidden content                 |
    --------| This content should be visible | 
            | hidden content                 | 
            | hidden content                 | 
    ----------------------------------------- 
   | Cell #2| hidden content                 |
    --------| This content should be visible | 
            | hidden content                 | 
            | hidden content                 | 
             --------------------------------
```

Comment: Ok, I think I have resolved on my own the first doubt, just replacing  colspan="2" by colspan="1" on the javascript function and code table. Just missing the second one...

Comment: cool!!, everything is ok now :D ( http://jsfiddle.net/jrick/U6h94/1/ )